# How to alter screen dimming routine on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: display, power-management, cron

My Android cellphone did the same thing. It had a mode/routine that kicked on every night. Some power feature.I edited the timer to go off at 3am and all has been peachy on my phone.
Ubuntu is doing the same as my phone but there is no place to adjust the Ubuntu routine. On Android it's called Night Mode.
It's not a true dim and also not a true darken feature. It's some kind of darkening display mode that is a combination of the 2.

How do I turn the night mode routine off?